# Evaluate custom javascript method (CircularJSON) with Jade

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug, stringify

I want to parse an object into client-side javascript through Jade. Normally this would work:

```jade
script var object = JSON.parse(#{JSON.stringify(object)});
```

but my `object` is [circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117470/passing-an-object-with-circular-references-from-server-to-client-side-javascript) and I need to do this

```jade
script var object = CircularJSON.parse(#{CircularJSON.stringify(object)});
```

but it throws the error

> ```
> Cannot call method 'stringify' of undefined
> ```

which I guess is because Jade doesn't recognise my `CircularJSON` method. 
Any way to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It could be `require`d and passed in the `locals`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007559/require-a-javascript-library-inside-jade/24007649#24007649)

```
response.render("index.jade", {CircularJSON : require('circular-json')});
```

[Or it could be defined as a function in the scope of jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940860/javascript-function-execution-inside-jade-template)

```
- var CircularJSON = function(e,t){function l(e,t,o){var u=[],...//whole function
script var player = CircularJSON.parse('!{CircularJSON.stringify(player)}');
```