# Require a javascript library inside Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

How do I `require` a library so that it works inside Jade.

Like if I want to be able to use [CircularJSON](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json) in Jade

```
script var object = #{CircularJSON.stringify(object)}
```

[I would basically need to define the function from that library into Jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962845/evaluate-custom-javascript-method-circularjson-with-jade/23963566#23963566)

```
- var CircularJSON = function(e,t){function l(e,t,o){var u=[],...//whole function
```

which would be impractical and possibly impossible for much more complex libraries.

Is there a way to somehow simply `require` it instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var myLib = require('../mylib');
response.render("index.jade", {
  lib  :  myLib
});
```

`index.jade` now has the myLib object. Now just use as you would anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Just require it in node and pass it to the template in the `locals`. `locals` can include functions as well entire modules, objects and scalar data.

Comment: The whole "locals" deal is quite confusing for me (pretty new to the node world). Is this a Jade, Node, or JS thing? Including some examples in your answer would be quite helpful.

Comment: locals is both a jade thing and an express thing. Templates take a string with some placeholders and replace the placeholders with real data values. The real data values are called the "locals". See true's answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Peter. Seems the main thing that's causing me confusion is entering the Node world without entering the Express world. I'm using Gulp for a custom static bulid system... posted [a related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617795/how-to-use-markdown-in-yaml-data-file-with-jade).

Answer (score 0):

I like to take an approach similar to [Peter Lyons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266795/peter-lyons) and Zhifeng Hu (in another post), but instead of requiring everything into locals, I just require "require", then I can pull things in as needed in my templates.

`app.use((req, res, next) => { res.locals.require = require; next() })`

and then in Jade/Pug

```
- const moment = require('moment')
div Created at: #{moment(data.createdAt).fromNow()}
```

Basically the same thing, but I can keep the require code in the template where it's used.

Comment: Note: [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) will only resolve paths against the original file it was passed to. This wouldn't matter when using libraries that are in node_modules (like `moment`) but relative paths (like `./x`, `../xx`) might not work if the jade file using the passed `require` is in a different directory.